# substring with variable last character SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of rows in a database column that look like this

```
AB01-52
AB01-52/1
AB01-53/2
AB01-54
```

I can get the `52` where there is no slash in the string but when I try to get it between the dash and the slash I either get an error or get the `52/1` for example

I have tried most of the researched solutions using substring and charindex but to no avail

Has anyone seen a solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Rick

Comment: Show the code you wrote that produces the wrong result.

Comment: case when  charindex('/'field1) = 0 then substring(field1,charindex('-',field1)+1 ,len(field1)) else charindex('/'field1) = 0 then substring(field1,charindex('-',field1)+1 ,len(field1))  else SUBSTRING(fiel1,CHARINDEX('-',field1)+1,CHARINDEX('/',field1)-CHARINDEX('-',field1)-1)

Comment: I also am unsure how your solutions with charindex/substring were to no avail. That is absolutely how you would solve your problem.

Comment: If all the values you wish to extract are the 6th and 7th characters in the string, this is easy to do. Are there more *variations* that need to be taken into account?

Comment: Nope no variations there is either a slash followed by a number or there is no slash

Comment: If no variations then just do - `SELECT SUBSTRING(col,CHARINDEX('-',col)+1,2) FROM Table`

Comment: The number can vary between 0 and 99999 (would be my top guess) so no it is not always the 6/7 chars sadly

Comment: So, there *are* variations. Update your question with a few more examples where the values you're seeking to extract are not all exactly 2 characters in length.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the characters positions (i.e. `/`) and use as length for `substring()`

```
substring(col, charindex('-', col)+1, len(col)-charindex('/', col)+1)
```

If the numbers have variable length then do the subtraction from both characters and use of *length*

```
substring(col, charindex('-', col)+1, charindex('/', col+'/')-charindex('-', col)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach....

```
with cte as(
select 'AB01-53/2' as C1
union
select 'AB01-54')

select left(right(c1,len(c1) - charindex('-',c1)),len(right(c1,len(c1) - charindex('-',c1))) - charindex('/',right(c1,len(c1) - charindex('-',c1)))+ 1)
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field is **ALWAYS** AAAA-BB[/CCC], then simply:

```
  SUNSTRING('AB01-52/1',6,2) ;
```

Of course, the `'AB01-52/1'` may be substituted by a variable or column name.

Comment: In that case, update your example so people (and me) can better understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer but it involves a 2 stage process

First add an additional slash to the column that contains the data where there is no slash at the moment ie AB01-52 becomes AB01-52/ the others like AB01-1023/01 remain the same

stage 2 use this code:

```
substring(right(col1,len(col1)-charindex('-',col1)),0,charindex('/',right(col1,len(col1)-charindex('-',col1))))
```

this allows me to get the middle string. The use of left and right by various people who contributed helped to get to this - however I still thing there should be an answer without stage 1

Thanks you all for your ideas which got me to this point